# What is the easiest way to run a word VBA script as many times as needed?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I know the question title is not clear, so hopefully I can clarify:

Consider the following VBA script (written by M. Paige):

```
Sub rem_space()
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    With myRange.Find
        .Text = " :"
        .Replacement.Text = ":"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
            Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```

This will replace each instance of " :" with ":".

The problem is that I have an arbitrary amount of spaces, and have to run it multiple times to eliminate all instances of " :".

So, what is the best way to modify this VBA script to make it have to only run once, resulting in any number of arbitrary spaces before a colon being removed.

Should the VBA script be recursive?

Should I search the document to determine the most spaces before a colon and then run the VBA script that number of times?

Would running the VBA script within a for loop say, 100 times catch everything?

What is the easiest solution to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one duplicates a call to `.Execute`, but doesn't rely on an infinite loop.

```
With myRange.Find
    .Text = " :"
    .Replacement.Text = ":"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue

        Do While .Found

            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        Loop
End With
```

Or perhaps a `Do...Loop While` loop instead.

```
With myRange.Find
    .Text = " :"
    .Replacement.Text = ":"

        Do 
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue

        Loop While .Found
End With
```

Comment: This looks ugly though (and defies [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) because the `.Execute` line is used twice.  If you don't like my approach, I'd suggest at least checking out the "Do...Loop While" instead.  That being said, there's nothing wrong with the infinite loop approach.

Comment: I don't like the infinite loop personally. I hadn't considered the Do...Loop While. Also not a huge fan, but I think this would be a good use case for it @roryap.

Comment: Definitely better. Thanks @roryap. The `Do...Loop While` solves the issue of setting `.Text` and `.Replacement.Text` at each iteration nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub rem_space()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

    Do While True
        With myRange.Find
            .Text = " :"
            .Replacement.Text = ":"

            If (Not .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
                Wrap:=wdFindContinue)) Then Exit Do
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```

It loops indefinitely with the `Do While True` and then exits only when the call to `.Execute` returns false.